# Prove $\alpha + \beta = \beta + \alpha \Rightarrow \alpha = \gamma n, \beta = \gamma m$ for some $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Here, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are some ordinals for which addition turns out to be commutative, and $\gamma$ is some ordinal division by which yields a natural quotient and zero remainder for both $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

I tried proving this by assuming this is not the case (and, for every $\gamma$, dividing $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by $\gamma$ produces non-zero remainder if the quotient is a natural), but I couldn't come to any contradiction.

Another approach is to notice that if $\alpha + \beta = \beta + \alpha$, then for any sets $A, B$ representing respectively $\alpha, \beta$ with $L_A, L_B$ being the corresponding (well-ordered) sets of limit elements, $L_A + L_B = L_B + L_A$ must hold (since $A = \mathbb{N} \times L_A$ modulo some countable set of elements greater than the last limit element, and so is $B$). This is similar to the original claim, and one would hope that the ordinal of, say, $L_A$ is smaller than $\alpha$, so this could be proved inductively, but as far as I know this is not generally the case: the equality might also hold.

So what's the nicest way to prove the claim?

Comment: What are $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: Some ordinals for which the equality holds.

Comment: It would be better to mention that this is about ordinals, explicitly in the question (and maybe the title too), not just in a tag and a comment.

Comment: For a start you need to use $y<x\geq \omega \implies y+x=x.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cantor normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_normal_form) works.

Assume that we have following Cantor normal forms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively:
$$\alpha = \omega^{\xi_0}\cdot a_0+\cdots + \omega^{\xi_n}\cdot a_n\quad\text{ and } \beta = \omega^{\xi_0}\cdot b_0+\cdots + \omega^{\xi_n}\cdot b_n$$

(Of course, there is no need that their Cantor normal form have same length and same set of exponents. However such problem can be easily overcome by adding additional $\omega^\eta$-terms with coefficient zero.)

Now consider the following lemma: if $\xi<\eta$ and $k<\omega$ then $\omega^\xi\cdot k + \omega^\eta = \omega^\eta$. It follow from the existence of $\mu\ge 1$ such that $\eta = \xi + \mu$.

Assume that $\alpha+\beta = \beta+\alpha$ as given in our problem. We will divide cases: if $a_0=0$, then $\alpha+\beta = \beta < \beta + \alpha$ when $\alpha>0$. (The case when $\alpha=0$ is trivial.) Hence $\alpha+\beta\neq \beta+\alpha$. The case $b_0=0$ can be handled similarly.

Now assume that $a_0,b_0\neq 0$. Then the previous lemma leads following equation:
$$\omega^{\xi_0}\cdot (a_0+b_0) + \omega^{\xi_1}\cdot b_1 + \cdots \omega^{\xi_n}\cdot b_n = \omega^{\xi_0}\cdot (a_0+b_0) + \omega^{\xi_1}\cdot a_1 + \cdots \omega^{\xi_n}\cdot a_n $$

By left-cancellation law, we have
$$\omega^{\xi_1}\cdot b_1 + \cdots \omega^{\xi_n}\cdot b_n =  \omega^{\xi_1}\cdot a_1 + \cdots \omega^{\xi_n}\cdot a_n $$
Therefore $a_1=b_1$, $\cdots$, $a_n=b_n$ by the uniqueness of the Cantor normal form. Now take
$$\gamma = \omega^{\xi_0} + \omega^{\xi_1}\cdots a_1+\cdots + \omega^{\xi_n}\cdot a_n$$
then you can check that $\alpha = \gamma\cdot a_0$ and $\beta = \gamma\cdot b_0$.

Comment: Your formula does not quite work that way. For instance, if $\alpha=\omega^2+\omega$ and $\beta$ is $3$, then $\alpha+\beta$ is not $\omega^2+3$, which is what your formula predicts.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo But your example does not satisfy $\alpha+\beta=\beta+\alpha$.

Comment: So? Look at the proof that you wrote.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I realize I should consider $a_0$ (or $b_0$) could be zero.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I fixed an error in my proof. I hope I did not make other mistakes...

Comment: That's great! I would never be able to see that you can throw away all smaller ordinals between $\omega^{\xi_0}$ on both sides, thanks to your lemma, and that's the key!